# Generate static API documentation from schema?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, koa

I've got Koa/Express apps and would like to generate a static documentation based on annotations to the different API routes.

Swagger seems to be good but all packages I found don't generate the documentation but host it with the API itself. 
I want the API documentation to be seperated from my API.

Are there modules other OS projects offering this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've the OpenAPI/Swagger spec, you can try [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) by going to https://editor.swagger.io. Under "Generate Client" select "HTML" or "Dynamic HTML"

Or you can use https://restunited.com to generate both SDKs and documentation with code sample. Here is an example: http://restunited.com/docs/6y2jvtvkgvst

Disclosure: I'm a top contributor to Swagger Codegen and founder of RESTUnited.com

Answer (score 0):

For those who found this question recently, here is the tool you can use. It is called TSOA: https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/